# url_for symfony showing "module=" and "action=" in result

Tags: url-routing, symfony1

I am using `url_for` as `url_for('changeLogin/changeLogin')` and getting the result:

> module=changeLogin/action=changeLogin

Why `module=` and `action=` are coming in result ?

Is there any configuration issue ?

Please help

PS: Using Symfony 1.0.22, PHP 5.4

Comment: what is your route definition? (Please use the tag symfony1 in the future ;) )

Comment: using default:
url:   /:module/:action/*

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I didn't code with this framework for 5 year

You have to create your route if you want symfony to link the url 'changeLogin/changeLogin' to your controller.

```
change_login_route:
  url:   /changeLogin/changeLogin
  param: { module: YourModule, action: yourAction }
```

Then use it like

```
url_for('@change_login_route')
```

Comment: Routing I am using is default for every url, otherwise I have to define it separately for every route, which is not a good practice as I have hundreds of routes with dynamic url building as well.

Do you have any idea, why url_for is behaving as such ? Or I have miss any configuration for routes ?

Comment: I have no Idea :/ Even when i was using this framework i was using the 1.4 :/ Good luck in your research